# I am wondering can I add a new electrical connection for a gas range to this line?

Tags: electrical

I found the electrical line with only with one receptacle for a garbage disposal. I am wondering can I add a new electrical connection for a gas range to this line?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the gas range only uses electric for clock and ignition you will be fine (given 20A circuit).  Being fine and passing inspection are two different things though.

However the real question is what the oven and disposal require and the size of the circuit.  In the manual for oven and disposal there should be information about circuit requirements.   My disposal for instance says that for a 20A circuit it may be shared with one other outlet.

So read the manual to see if this will work for you.  If you gave us the exact models we could answer better.  If this is permitted work, then just ask your inspector.  Your configuration is very normal in my area but not normal in others.

Answer (score -1):

I say no.

Reason #1: The NEC (I only have 2014 available to me)

> ## National Electric Code 2014 Edition
>
> ### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> #### III. Required Outlets
>
> ***210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets***
>
> **(B) Small Appliances**
>
> (2) No Other Outlets.
>
> The two or more small appliance branch circuits specified in 210.52(B)(1) shall have no
>   other outlets.
>
> *Exception No. 1: A receptacle installed solely for the electrical supply to and support of an electric clock in any of the rooms specified in 210.52(B)(1).*
>
> *Exception No.2: Receptacles installed to provide power for supplemental equipment and lighting on gas-fired ranges, ovens, or counter-mounted cooking units.*

Reason #2: a GFCI will not provide the equipment with an adequate ground path.  Some municipalities may allow this but I would pull a new circuit for this appliance.

(oops, I am of course *assuming* that the disposal circuit has GFCI protection)

Comment: Why wouldn't a GFCI protected circuit provide an adequate ground path? I also don't understand how 210.52 (B)(2) fits in this situation.

Comment: That is how I interpret that section of the NEC.  I am interested in hearing why you think it would be allowed (I'm not being coy)

Comment: Second @Tester101's question. A GFCI will let you operate (more) safely without a ground if you must, but normally GFCI outlets do accept a grounded connector and are wired with ground present.

Comment: I agree with you keshlam *if* the ground is present.  That information wasn't provided by the OP however.

Comment: Also, if the gas range has an electronic ignition then there is significant likelihood of nuisance tripping the GFCI no matter the circuit configuration.

Comment: Totally agree with Tester here. This section of the codes does NOT apply at all. All this says is that a SABC is allowed to feed a gas range receptacle, nothing more. Also, WHAT makes you say a GFI might _"not provide the equipment with an adequate ground path"_ ?? This makes absolutely no sense. WHY would you assume no adequate ground and GFI protection??